# Describing historical performance of probability predictions

Tags: probability, descriptive-statistics

I'm trying to think of a descriptive statistic in the context of sports betting.
Some background:
Sportsbooks post odds such as -150, +200, etc... for moneyline bets (aka betting on winner). 
These odds can be converted to explicit probabilities of who the winner will be.
Source: https://www.sportsbookreviewsonline.com/sportsbettingarticles/sportsbettingarticle10.htm

I'd like to measure how well a sportsbooks probabilities have behaved in the long run historically.
I can think of binning these values into various probabilities, and seeing how well they behave.

- So have games with explicit winning probability of 55-60% won 58% historically? Surely there will be some variation between sportsbooks - maybe some sportsbooks have it at 50% and others 60% over some period of time.
- I can do the above for all increments of 5% from 0%-100%.

Example of dataset I'm using
[image]

Is there a good measure to answer the above question without binning the data and keeping it continuous?

Comment: see [scoring rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_rule)